# Selected directory is not a valid home for JDK - Intellij IDEA on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, java-8, intellij-13

After installing Intellij Idea 14, with OracleJDK 1.8 u25 (64 bit) on my 14.04 Ubuntu system, I cannot configure the Java SDK to use any JDK. When I navigate to Module Settings->SDK and click configure SDK, the add button, and then select `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25` in the dialog, I get an error popup stating that "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK."

I've checked the contents of the directory, which contains a `bin` folder with both `java` and `javac` inside, a `lib` folder and a `jre` folder.

I've tried selecting each of those in turn, to no avail, which I expected.

Comment: @A1ternat1ve Not a duplicate in the sense that accepted answer doesn't apply since the folder in question is a full jdk install, unlike as within that case. According to the answer, one of `bin`, `lib`, or `jre` was missing or incomplete.

Comment: Ok. My apologies. I din't read it properly.

Comment: Does IntelliJ have permissions to read that folder?

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/130186/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-usr-directory

Comment: @Evan Thanks! That provided me with a solution to the question. I've posted an answer with the method I used.

Comment: Heh, good job everyone!

Comment: Check you installed the jdk (not only the jre) : sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Evan Knowles posted a link to https://askubuntu.com/questions/130186/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-usr-directory. It provided me with the solution to the problem.

Instead of using the JDK at `/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25`, I instead used the JDK at `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_25`. The reasons that this works rather than the other are explained in detail within the link.

Answer (score 76):

I had the same problem, in my case I wasn't able to select any of the "*openjdk*" directories under `/usr/lib/jvm/`, I solved with:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

When restarting intellij it will find the path to the jdk automatically.

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04 I did not have a `/usr/local/java/` folder.  This worked for me, however.  Right after doing this IJ was able to let me select `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 with openjdk-8-jdk, the folder can now be selected

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Works for debian 9 stretch, the folder can now be selected

Comment: Thanks, save my day! Works on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and Intellij Idea Community Edition 2019 3.4

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 and IntelliJ IDEA 2020 also worked. Thank You!

Answer (score 26):

For the ones who run into this problem even though you select the right directory under `/usr/lib/jvm`, there is something you should know : The directories under `/usr/lib/jvm` are created when your system installs the minimum set of java tools. But it doesn't mean you have the development files available. You need to install the development files :

```
sudo apt-get install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

After installing this package, try to select the directory again and it should work.

Comment: This is especially necessary if you want to install any jdk8+, thanks @vdegenne

Answer (score 3):

I came across this error because I did not have `JAVA_HOME` set.

Adding `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` (for openjdk 11 in my case) and `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` to my ~/.bashrc and then running `source ~/.bashrc` solved the problem for me.