# Selected directory is not a valid home for JDK - Intellij IDEA2016 on Windows

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I met a problem when I set the sdk for Intellij Idea2016

Not the same as [Selected directory is not a valid home for JDK - Intellij IDEA on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116439/selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-jdk-intellij-idea-on-ubuntu).

My Idea can set JDK1.7 successfully, but when set the jdk1.8, it will warn "Selected directory is not a valid home for JDK":

[image: idea]

can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you have an environment variable `JAVA_HOME` in your system ?

Comment: yeah, and my java_home is jdk1.8

Comment: For which one it is pointing? _91 or _92? It could be your issue if it is pointing to _91 and you are trying to set II to _92. If you change the environment don't forget to close the II and open it again

Comment: I fixed it yesterday, you can see my answer below. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue after whole morning.
Maybe the Intellij Idea 2016.1.3 doesn't support the latest two version what are jdk1.8.0_91 and jdk1.8.0_92.

I try the previous version of jdk1.8.0_77
here is the archive download
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html.

[image]

Hope you would resolve the issue if met.