# IntelliJ IDEA adding JDK 10: “The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK”

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, java-10

I'm creating this question only because the duplicate questions I found were marked with [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713414/intellij-idea-the-selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-jdk) and [Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116439/selected-directory-is-not-a-valid-home-for-jdk-intellij-idea-on-ubuntu/30116654) respectively, whereas I am experiencing this issue on macOS

I have IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2 installed, with JDK 8 added, and want to add JDK 10. After downloading and installing Oracle's JDK 10, and attempting to add `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home` as a new JDK to IntelliJ, I got the error message

> The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK

despite the fact that the path and file permissions of this JDK 10 directory were seemingly all aligned with the JDK 8 ones.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turned out that **upgrading to the newest IntelliJ IDEA** version was (for some reason) what was required. After installing IDEA 2018.1, I was able to add JDK 10 without issue.

Comment: Which is like the first thought after reading the question title :-)

Comment: But after upgrading to Intellij IDEA 2018, I'm encountering at least four different types of bugs that severely affect my productivity, none of which existed in the 2017 version.

Comment: does not work for me with IDEA 2018.2 for java 10 and 11 :/

Comment: @Zarathustra were you able to get Java 10 to work with IDEA 2018.2?

Comment: @Gabe Vacaliuc downloading it from openjdk directly instead of via apt / yum